# File Path Created In Cell Contains Trailing Spaces At End

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Bonjour,

I have a formula in cell `A1` that creates a file path string based on the contents of other cells (i.e., year from `B1`, account from `C1`).

`A1` Formula:

```
="C:\MF\"&B1&"\"&C1&"_Report"
```

My problem is that when I go to copy/paste the file path that is produced in the cell, I have a bunch of spaces at the end that appears to be tab indents (i.e., "`C:\MF\2019\69420_Report`      ") and this results in the file explorer not able to locate the exact file when I run my macro.

I've tried functions, such as `TRIM` and `CLEAN`, but I cannot get these extra spaces to go away... I'm sure this is a simple fix (I hope) however, I was hoping some fresh eyes might have an idea on how to solve this.

Functions used to remove unnecessary spaces:

```
=TRIM(="C:\MF\"&B1&"\"&C1&"_Report")

=TRIM(CLEAN(="C:\MF\"&B1&"\"&C1&"_Report"))
```

I expect to return the file path produced in A1 to NOT have those extra trailing spaces at the end, but I've had no luck :( Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. I placed `2019` in cell B1 and `69240` in C1. I then copied your exact formula beginning with `=` into cell A1 and hit Enter. I copied the path that was placed into A1 (clicked in A1, hit Ctrl+C) and pasted it directly into Notepad with Ctrl+V, and it contains no trailing characters at all, but exactly what it should contain.

Comment: I also tested by opening Windows Explorer and using Ctrl+V to paste the content into the location bar. Still no trailing content of any kind; the text cursor appears immediately after the ending `t` in `_Report` as it should, and the path would be entirely valid if that folder existed on my machine.

Comment: Figure out what that last character is with `CODE` and then `SUBSTITUTE` a blank string maybe.

Comment: As it is not possible to reproduce this issue, could you send a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who took the time to attempt to resolve my problem. I was never able to deduce why the training spaces were staying on (Seriously, I promise these exist and would not go away lol), but to work around this issue, I utilized the following VBA to open the cell containing the dynamic file path:

```
'Sample worksheet = worksheet containing file path
'Cell D1 contains the file path made by the other cells
Workbooks.Open(Worksheets("Sample").Range("D1").Value)
```